Non-commuting matrix exponential lowerbound
Given a symmetric matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and two vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^d, b\in \mathbb{R}_+^d$. Assume that $b_i>0$, and
$$
b = \text{diag} (\exp(\text{diag}(v) -A)). 
$$
Can we get a lower bound of $\min_i v_i$ in terms of $b$ and $A$?

The bottleneck here is that $A$ and $\text{diag}(v)$ are not commutative. I did some computations and verified that as $\min_i v_i \to -\infty$, the corresponding entry of $\text{diag} (\exp(\text{diag}(v) -A))\to 0$. This indicates a lower bound is possible.
